Combinatorics questions, people in a row, i'th person not standing right to (i-1)th person
The question goes like: There are n people in a row, how many ways are there to rearrange them, such that for all $0 \le i \le n-1$, the people who stood in original (i+1)th place, is not standing right next to the original people that was in i'th place.
My approach: i was thinking about inclusion exclusion principle.
|Ai| - the number of ways to rearrangee the people in a row, such that i and i+1 standing together.
now im stuck on the case of $|A_i \cap A_j|$, because there are two possibilities, for example, if i have the row $1 2 3456$, i can either choose 12 34, or 12 23.
How can i overcome this issue? thanks in advance, because I'm not certain on how to calculate $|A_i \cap A_j|$ and so on.

What does "right to" mean?  Do you mean immediately next to and to the right or do you simply mean somewhere to the right?  In any case, a natural start is to solve the problem for several small $n$.  If nothing else, that gives you a way to check your eventual formula.

@lulu it next to, ill fix it

So, then, this is a duplicate, yes?

@lulu i think it's indeed the same, but the answer was not using PIE, im looking into PIE.

this is A000255.  I would think recursive methods are the way to go here.

Note:  post edit, I still don't understand the rules.  Please try to be clear.  Writing "right next to", as you do, would exclude both $(i, i+1)$ and $(i+1,i)$.    In the first version of your post, you appeared to only want to exclude $(i, i+1)$ and that's what the duplicate I linked to considers.  I suggest:  Work this out explicitly for $n=3$ and add that to your post, just to remove ambiguities.  If you really mean to exclude both orders, then the answer is $0$, right?  But if you only mean what is meant in the duplicate then $132, 213, 321$ are all good making the answer $3$.

Can you please explain the approach with the recursive method?

I don't think I could add much to the posted solution.

Oh im sorry it's exactly the same, thanks again lulu

Every problem is not  a piece of PIE !

@trueblueanil I strongly suspect that this particular problem is solvable (analytically) by Inclusion-Exclusion, through the use of Stars and Bars internally, in the computation of $~T_2, T_3, \cdots.~$  See this quasi-answer.

@trueblueanil I must admit defeat, and withdraw my previous comment.  I tried and failed to use the methods in my previous comment to attack this problem.  I started by letting $~S_k~$ denote the set of permutations where a violation occurred at position $~k,~$ where $~k \in {1,2,\cdots,n-1}.~$ The difficulty is that when computing one of the groups of terms in $~T_r,~$ by scrutinizing the variables $~x_2,\cdots,x_r,~$ it is insufficient to determine how many of them are exactly equal to $~0.~$ You must further examine how these zero variables are positioned.  ...see next comment

For example, when computing $~T_4,~$ the enumeration of $~S_1 \cap S_2 \cap S_4 \cap S_5~$ will be different than the enumeration of $~S_1 \cap S_2 \cap S_3 \cap S_5.~$  I also considered redefining $~S_k~$ to denote the permutations where the elements $~k,k+1~$ occurred consecutively, somewhere in the permutation.  Unfortunately, I also wasn't able to find a way to successfully use Stars and Bars internally, with this alternate approach.

@user2661923 what do you mean by $S1∩S2∩S3∩S5.$?

@csmathstudent8 that is a complicated question.  In one of my comments to this posted question, you will find a link to a quasi-answer.  Within that link, you will find two Inclusion-Exclusion links.  Please examine those two Inclusion-Exclusion links, and then leave me another comment, if you still have a question.
